# input text change onclick button value

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, button, switchers

Actually i want to create a page switcher, all i need for this is an input with type text where will be entered the number of the page, and i have the second input with type button and onclick value:

```
<input type="text" value="#number of the page#" />
<input type="button" onclick="_go_page_('cf_pages_form_name1','#number of the page#');" />
```

I cant figure it out how to take this #number of the page# and put it in onclick dynamically using javascript... please smb help!

Comment: is #number some variable that contains the page number of the current page??

Comment: @3nigma nope, just the number that user will have to enter to go to the page he want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="txtPageNumber" value="2" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="click" onclick="_go_page_('cf_pages_form_name1','#number of the page#');" />


$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#btn").click(function(){

       var $val = $("#txtPageNumber").val();
        alert($val);
            _go_page_('cf_pages_form_name1',$val);

    });


});




});
```

Comment: this is ur code i modified to make it work properly ) `<input type="text" id="txtPageNumber" value="" /><input type="button" id="gotoPage" onclick=""/>$("#gotoPage").click(function(){var abr = $("#txtPageNumber").val();_go_page_('cf_pages_form_name1',abr);});`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `number` is the id of the text field.

You can get the value of the text field like this:

```
$('#number').val();
```

And pass that is the onclick event

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ID on the page selector input to get the value.

```
function goToPage(pageNumber) {
  // go to pageNumber
}

&lt;input type="text" id="pageSelector" value="#number of the page#" />
&lt;input type="button" onclick="goToPage($('#pageSelector').val())" />
```

You've tagged this with jQuery so I'm assuming you're using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

lets your input type is like this

then in jquery try something like this...

```
$('#pageNo').keyup(function(){
 pageNo =    $(this).val()
 }
```

then pass this to your button onclick function

Answer (score 0):

i will answer in "very easy to understand" without jquery:

you have to get the value of the first inputfield. this should your function do. but first the inputfield needs an id(f.g. 'number').

code in function:

```
var pagenumber = document.getElementById('number').value;
```

then you have to put the number into the url (document.href).